# Yii: Display 2nd DB Content in CGridView

Tags: php, yii, grid

I'm using Yii-1.1.13. I have two database, I have configured both in `protected/config/main.php` as below.

```
  'db2'=>array(
   'class'   => 'CDbConnection' ,
   'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database2',
   'emulatePrepare' => true,
   'username' => 'zzzzz',
   'password' => 'zzzzz',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
  ),

  'db'=>array(
   'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database1',
   'emulatePrepare' => true,
   'username' => 'xxxxx',
   'password' => 'xxxxx',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
  ),
```

I'm using below code to show the count in [Yii CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView), it's working fine. this will connect *database1*.

**models**

```
 <?     
public function search()
{       
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
 $criteria->select='std_id ,count(*) as counts';
 $criteria->condition = "sdate between '$this->startdate' and '$this->enddate'";
 $criteria->group ='std_id';
 return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array( 
    'criteria'=>$criteria,      
    'pagination' => array( 'pageSize' => 30 ),
    ));                         
}       
?>
```

**view**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'std_id-grid', 
   'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
   'columns'=>array(    
    'std_id',                   
    'counts',                   
    ),                          

   )); ?>
```

---

In another models, I have below code to display the users details that will connect with database2. Its not working, what is wrong in that. I have tried with two different ways.
see the below Type-1 and Type-2.

I have referred the [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/) link to connect multiple database in Yii.

**models**

```
    <?

         class Usr extends SecDB
    {
    ...
    ..
             public function getDbConnection()
            {
                return self::getSecDbConnection();
        //We need to override this method in the models representing the 
    //advertising database to return the second DB connection.
        }


    public function search()
    {

     // Type -1 Not working
     /*$row = Yii::app()->db2->createCommand(array(
        'select' => array('id', 'name', 'date_created'),
        'from' => 'accounts',
        'where' => "type = 'USERS'",
        ))->queryAll();

     return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$row,
        ));
    */

     // Type -2 Not working

     $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
     $criteria->select='id,name,date_created';
     $criteria->condition = "type = 'USERS'";
     return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,

  ));
    }

 ?>
}
```

**view**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'users-grid',
   'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
   'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'date_created'
    ),

   )); ?>
```

I have overwrite the db connection. but it's not working, nothing is coming in browser.

---

I have `SecDB.php` in protected/components/SecDB.php

```
<?php

class SecDB extends CActiveRecord {
    private static $db2 = null;

    public static function getSecDbConnection()
    {
        if (self::$db2 !== null){
            return self::$db2;
        }else
 {      
            self::$dbcc = Yii::app()->db2;
            if (self::$db2 instanceof CDbConnection)
            {
                self::$db2->setActive(true);
                return self::$db2;
            }
            else
                throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db2" CDbConnection application component.'));
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: read this comment : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/#c4816

Answer (score -1):

Yoy need rewrite getDBConnection() in model

```
public function getDbConnection()
    {
        if (self::$conection !== null)
            return self::$conection;
        else
        {
            self::$conection = Yii::app()->db2;
            if (self::$conection instanceof CDbConnection)
            {
                self::$conection->setActive(true);
                return self::$conection;
            }
            else
                throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db2" CDbConnection application component.'));
        }
    }
```

For dev mode, in web/index.php add

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```

EDIT:

```
<?php

class SecDB extends CActiveRecord {
    private static $db2;

    public function getDbConnection()
    {
        if (self::$db2 !== null){
            return self::$db2;
        }else
 {      
            self::$db2 = Yii::app()->db2;
            if (self::$db2 instanceof CDbConnection)
            {
                self::$db2->setActive(true);
                return self::$db2;
            }
            else
                throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db2" CDbConnection application component.'));
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I have updated my question, I have specified in my code to overwite the db connection in getDbConnection()

Comment: OK, you code is wrong, you assign self::$dbcc = Yii::app()->db2, and return self::$db2 that is null, change self::$db2 by self::$dbcc and add public static $dbcc in your model

Comment: In my code m I'm using dbcc. In fourm everyone should understand, So I have changed dbcc as db2 in post , inthat plane I have forget to change dbcc as db2. Now I have changed as db2